"Квартира" vs "флат"
When I speak to Russian family, and use "квартира", I always get corrected to use the word "flat".
But in learning Russian, the text says that "квартира" is the correct translation of apartment.
Is there a difference in these words in Russian?  Or is "flat" currently more popular than "квартира"?

Can you give an example of how they use this word? Do they indeed say "флэт" in Russian sentence, e.g. "У меня трехкомнатный флэт"? This is absolutely not standard Russian, and not even any widespread Russian dialect (at least within Russia).

Also, can you add a location where that family lives? Do they live in Russia, or is it e.g. a Russian-speaking family in the US?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In Russia флэт is very narrowly used (and obsolete) slang, in Russian-speaking communities in English-speaking countries it might be the case that флэт is used, as it quite often happens with shorter alternatives, like saying "турка" instead of "индейка"

My guess is that this family is living in the UK. They may be using the term флэт simply because that is what the estate agent or the neighbors call it. Or they may perceive the word флэт as refering to a particular building layout common in the UK but rare in Russia. When words pass from language to language they often aquire very specific meaning or connotations absent in the donor language.

This is not a word in standard Russian and can be used only by those who intentionally mix Russian and English words.

Just to follow up, I am currently in Ufa, a city in Russia. I think the comment by @Anixx is correct: It is from my partially English speaking relatives who are speaking Russlesh!

The word флэт does exist in Russian, but its use is constrained to slangs of subcultures (like hippie or stilyagi), and imitations thereof.
The word апартаменты (in the plural) is also sometimes used, but it usually refers either to a big, luxury apartment, or to a short-term rental or secondary apartment. It also has a separate legal meaning in some Russian-speaking countries.
In mainstream Russian, the word for "apartment" (or "flat" in British English), where regular people live their regular lives, is квартира, as you have correctly learned.

IANAL, but: "Апартаменты" isn't just a fancy name for luxury "flat". It's an altogether different legal status. From a legal point of view, "апартаменты" are closer to non-residential commercial real estate (offices, hotels). One can't have "апартаменты" as their permanent place of residence (постоянной регистрации в апартаментах нет). "Апартаменты" can be reposessed for debts. Tax deductions do not apply to them. They are not considered "многоквартирный дом", and building codes that apply to residential buildings do not apply to them, too...

@IgorG: that's what the part after "or" tries to cover (didn't want to go into too much detail there). The meaning of "luxury apartment" predates that: Например, зачинатель трудового движения, названного его же именем, А.Г. Стаханов получил в качестве поощрения не просто благоустроенную квартиру, а настоящие апартаменты со специально обставленным кабинетом.
[Н. Б. Лебина. Cоветская повседневность: нормы и аномалии. От военного коммунизма к большому стилю // Cоветская повседневность: нормы и аномалии. От военного коммунизма к большому стилю, 2015]
